# Insert text in-between rows in a table

Tags: tables, formatting, pdftex, tabularx

I'm trying to achieve the following effect:

```
+------------+---------+
| Col1  Col2 |         |
+------------+---------+
| Value 1    | Value 2 |
| Value 3    | Value 4 |

Text goes here...

| Value 5    | Value 6 |
+------------+---------+
```

In other words, I would like to insert text into a table, and have the table carry on as normal after that. I've been stymied as to how to implement this so far.

For example:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Branch instruction address} & \textbf{Next instruction address} \\ \hline
    \texttt{0xd4f30d2C} & \texttt{0xd4f30d60} \\ \hline
    \texttt{0xd4f30d0f} & \texttt{0xd4f30ddd} \\ \hline

    <Text goes here>     

    \texttt{0xd4f30c4f} & \texttt{0xd4f30d6c} \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I think this is what `\noalign` does, but please can we have an MWE to work on?

Comment: it might also be possible to define a multi-column "paragraph" cell with no verticals at the ends and input the text in that.  then it would just be considered part of the table.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [Barbara Beeton's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton) suggestion, I came up with this:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Branch instruction address} & \textbf{Next instruction address} \\ \hline
    \texttt{0xd4f30d2C} & \texttt{0xd4f30d60} \\ \hline
    \texttt{0xd4f30d0f} & \texttt{0xd4f30ddd} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots\vspace{0.2em}}\\ \hline
    \texttt{0xd4f30c4f} & \texttt{0xd4f30d6c} \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not too sure of what you want: should the inter-row text be full page width or only table width? Any way here are three ways that offer a solution for both cases. Note vertical padding with the `\makegapedcells` command from `makecell` does not work inside a `blockarray` environment, nor `\extrarowheight`, and I had to change the value of `\arraystretch`+ some manual correction :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, blkarray, makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setcellgapes{6pt}
  \renewcommand\cellalign{lc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c| }
    \hline
    Column 1 & Column 2
    \\
    \hline
    Value 1 & Value 2 \\
    Value 3 & Value 4 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\makecell{Some text there…\\
    Some more text here…}}\\
    Value 5 & Value 6 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\vskip 3ex

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X|c|c| X}
    \cline{2-3}
      & Column 1 & Column 2 &
    \\
    \cline{2-3}
      & Value 1 & Value 2 & \\
      & Value 3 & Value 4 & \\
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{%
    Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo.
    Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan
    bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit
    mollis.} \\%
      & Value 5 & Value 6 & \\
    \cline{2-3}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\vskip 3ex

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.667}
\begin{blockarray}{|c|c|}
        \BAhline
        Column 1 & Column 2
        \\
        \BAhline
        Value 1 & Value 2 \\
        Value 3 & Value 4 \\
\begin{block}{\BAmulticolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}}
\noalign{\vskip1.5ex}
\makecell{Some text there…\\
 Some more text here…}\\[1.5ex]
 \end{block}
        Value 5 & Value 6 \\
        \BAhline
\end{blockarray}
    \end{table}
    \vfill\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

[image]